# "Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"{\" Logstash config error

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, logstash, tls1.2

I got this error when i try to start my Logstash:

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/fortigate_test_bkb.conf
```

Error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and 

will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: Unknown module: org.jruby.dist specified to --add-opens
WARNING: Unknown module: org.jruby.dist specified to --add-opens
WARNING: Unknown module: org.jruby.dist specified to --add-opens
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs errors to the console
[INFO ] 2020-10-15 12:34:57.813 [main] runner - Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.9.2", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04 on 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
[WARN ] 2020-10-15 12:34:59.045 [LogStash::Runner] multilocal - Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[ERROR] 2020-10-15 12:35:01.531 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] agent - Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"{\" at line 9, column 6 (byte 68) after input {\nport ", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:183:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:69:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:44:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:357:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[INFO ] 2020-10-15 12:35:02.083 [Api Webserver] agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[INFO ] 2020-10-15 12:35:06.868 [LogStash::Runner] runner - Logstash shut down.
```

This is my logstash config in `/etc/logstash/conf.d/xxx.conf`:

```
#input {
#udp {
#port => 514
#type => firewall
#}
#}

input {
port => 514
type => firewall
#port => 5044
#ssl => true
ssl_enable => true
#ssl_key => "/etc/logstash/config/certs/lnxlogstash01.pkcs8.key"
#ssl_certificate => "/etc/logstash/config/certs/lnxlogstash01.crt"
}

filter {
if [type] == "firewall" {
mutate {
add_tag => ["fortigate"]
}
grok {
break_on_match => false
match => [ "message", "%{SYSLOG5424PRI:syslog_index}%{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]
overwrite => [ "message" ]
tag_on_failure => [ "failure_grok_fortigate" ]
}

kv { }

if [msg] {
mutate {
replace => [ "message", "%{msg}" ]
}
}
mutate {
convert => { "duration" => "integer" }
convert => { "rcvdbyte" => "integer" }
convert => { "rcvdpkt" => "integer" }
convert => { "sentbyte" => "integer" }
convert => { "sentpkt" => "integer" }
convert => { "cpu" => "integer" }
convert => { "disk" => "integer" }
convert => { "disklograte" => "integer" }
convert => { "fazlograte" => "integer" }
convert => { "mem" => "integer" }
convert => { "totalsession" => "integer" }
}
mutate {
add_field => [ "fgtdatetime", "%{date} %{time}" ]
add_field => [ "loglevel", "%{level}" ]
replace => [ "fortigate_type", "%{type}" ]
replace => [ "fortigate_subtype", "%{subtype}" ]
remove_field => [ "msg", "message", "date", "time", "eventtime" ]
}
date {
match => [ "fgtdatetime", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
#locale => "en"
#timezone => "NZ"
remove_field => [ "fgtdatetime" ]
}
#geoip {
#source => "srcip"
#target => "geosrcip"
#add_field => [ "[geosrcip][coordinates]", "%{[geosrcip][longitude]}" ]
#add_field => [ "[geosrcip][coordinates]", "%{[geosrcip][latitude]}" ]
#}
#geoip {
#source => "dstip"
#target => "geodstip"
#add_field => [ "[geodstip][coordinates]", "%{[geodstip][longitude]}" ]
#add_field => [ "[geodstip][coordinates]", "%{[geodstip][latitude]}" ]
#}
#mutate {
#convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
#}

}
}

output {
#if [host] == "10.a.b.c" {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "https://192.168.2.51:9200"
index => "fortinet-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}
}

#output {
#elasticsearch {
#hosts => "192.168.2.51:9200"
#cacert => '/etc/logstash/config/certs/ca.crt'
#user => 'logstash_writer'
#password => '##local01'
#index => "fortinet-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
#}
#}
```

The problem ist since i start security setting in my ELK-Cluster the new input and output part of my logstash conf cause this error above. I checked other threads with simular problems by checking the syntax, missing prackets etc, but everythin seems to be ok unless i want to start it.

the old part:

```
#input {
#udp {
#port => 514
#type => firewall
#}
#}
```

...

```
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "https://xxx:9200"
index => "fortinet-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}
```

used to work fine withour any error (bevore applying elastic security features) mainly from this post:  https://www.elastic.co/de/blog/configuring-ssl-tls-and-https-to-secure-elasticsearch-kibana-beats-and-logstash

My Logstash.yml contains this:

```
path.data: /var/lib/logstash
pipeline.ordered: auto
path.logs: /var/log/logstash
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: logstash_system
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: 'xxx'
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: [ 'https://<ip-of-elasticsearch-server>:9200' ]
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authority: /etc/logstash/config/certs/ca.crt
```

can someone help me plz. If you need more info, let me know

Comment: In the input part, you're missing the input plugin part (which was present in the commented input part)

Comment: I know. But wich plugin sould i use? I do not use Beats from the Tutorial. My firewall is simply sending his log to the ip address of my logstash cluster. Noone from this list seems to fit:[link] (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html)

Comment: udp, like in the old part?

Comment: if i use udp, there will be an error telling me with tls/ssl plugin udp is not supported. I'm confused.